Who pays the cost of Star Alliance lounge usage for cross-airline access?
Suppose I am a Star Alliance Gold member via say Turkish Airlines frequent flier program however my usual flight pattern leads me to use another star alliance airline, say Air India. Ergo I use Air India's lounges all the time.
Who foots the bill, TK or AI? Is there an interline agreement for compensation?
Just curious how lounge usage works.
What if there is assymetric use i.e. lots of TK gold members use AI flights and lounges but few in the reverse direction?
Does star alliance make airlines compensate each other for lounge use?

Frequent flyer programmes are in general so ridiculously profitable (for the airlines) that I suspect that the costs of operating a lounge are pretty much negligible in the grand scheme of things.

The airlines make much more profits from code shares and connecting tickets than the peanuts that the lounges cost them. I doubt they even bother accounting for that.

If the passenger uses AI flights then it’s AI making money and indirectly granting the privilege to the passenger, even though enrolled in the TK programme… but more generally, in your opinion, who should pay? The airline(s) the passenger is flying on today? The airline operating the programme the passenger is enrolled in? The airline(s) on which the passenger flew until now and got him status? That quickly becomes quite complex. Anyway, all in all, it should more or less balance out globally…

@jcaron Thanks. I've no opinion on who should pay just checking the ground reality of who pays! :)

As a analogy in the day of land lines in the USA different carriers used to pay others termination charges for calls.

What did your own research leave unclear about that, please? What did your own airlines' documentation and your own search-engine results not cover?

As a rule of thumb, each airline pays per passenger per use. So if you wave your TK elite card to get into an AI lounge, AI sends the bill to TK; and if an AI elite card holder uses a TK lounge, TK sends the bill to AI.
For most routes most of the time, usage is roughly equal at both ends, so it's plus minus zero at the end of the day.

Today, where every boarding pass get scanned, that makes sense. But I distinctly remember earlier times where they just look at your printed boarding pass and as long as there was "*G" on it, you where in. As far as I remember no one took a written record of my entry.

@Hilmar I presume they still added a tally mark to a written log somewhere.  They didn't care who entered, just that somebody did.

You don't have to count the individuals. You only have to count the number of airplanes that arrive and depart. That gives you passenger numbers, which gives you lounge numbers. You might count occasionally for calibration or correction, but that's it.

@NeanDerThal wouldn't bilateral agreements become too difficult? Given that Star alliance has more than a  dozen airlines that would mean a lot of agreements!

@lambshaanxy: I agree that they don't care who enters, but they sure need to track on whose program you enter. I used to just walk up the LH senator lounge, show my boarding pass to the person out front and I was in (sometimes with a guest). There was no record keeping (since the person was in front of the door, not inside at the desk).
